# Dividing a network into subnets

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I'm finding it very hard to understand IP subnetting.

The things I already know how to do: Given an IP-adres and a subnet mask, I'm able to find all ip adresses in the subnet. Given an ip adres like 145.244.0.0/14, I'm able to find the subnet mask.

The things I don't know how to do is an exercise like this: Dividing a network say 192.168.0/24 into subnets. Each subnet must contain at least 10 hosts. Which are the first seven subnets?

How would I go about finding a solution for such exercise? 
I'm supposed to find the Subnet adres, the subnet mask, the first host IP, the last host IP and the broadcast adress.

Note that this isn't some sort of homework, I have the solution in my book, but I don't know where it's coming from.

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a question like that, you start by figuring out how many bits you need to cover that many hosts:

10 hosts, `2^4 = 16` (minus 2 for ID and broadcast). `32-4 = 28`, so you're going to use a /28 subnet.

Using your knowledge of how to find IPs in the subnet, you can work backwards from here. You can also list out all the subnets by adding 16, or by working backwards from the IPs again:

```
192.168.0/24 (given supernet)
  192.168.0/28
  192.168.16/28
  192.168.32/28
  192.168.48/28
  192.168.64/28
  ...
```

Caveat: Most of these training exercises consider the first and last subnets to be unusable, as well as the first and last IP in each subnet. However, there is a slightly [nonstandard method](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/dynamic-address-allocation-resolution/13711-40.html) allowing their use.

Comment: Is "subnet zero" really problematic in practice, or is Cisco merely stuck in classful world?

Comment: The opposite, Cisco allows it (with the config option). The original RFC 950 prohibited it, but Cisco (and probably a few other vendors) now allow it in accordance with RFC 1875.

Answer (score 1):

> Dividing a network say 192.168.0/24 into subnets. Each subnet must contain at least 10 hosts. Which are the first seven subnets?

First, choose a subnet size that would result in subnets large enough for 12 addresses (network + 10 hosts + broadcast), but small enough to fit 7 subnets within your current /24 prefix.

- For 12 host addresses, you need at least 4 bits (2<sup>3</sup> = 8 < 12, but 2<sup>4</sup> = 16 > 12).
- For 7 subnets, you need at least 3 bits (2<sup>2</sup> = 4 < 7, but 2<sup>3</sup> = 8 > 7).

Since you have a /24, that is 8 bits remaining (out of 32), you have only two choices:

- 3 subnet bits + 5 host bits
- 4 subnet bits + 4 host bits

These options mean /(24 + 3) = /27 and /(24 + 4) = /28 subnets respectively.

Generally, I would choose /28 for *slightly* easier calculations, as it divides the last octet exactly in half. (This does not matter much in IPv4, but makes life a bit easier in IPv6, where addresses are written in 4-bit hex digits.)

---

Now list all /27 (or /28) subnets within the given /24 network. If you have 3 subnet bits and 5 host bits, keep incrementing the address by 2<sup>5</sup>, so that the 4th octet will be:

- 000x xxxx → 0000 0000 → 0 → 192.168.0.0/27
- 001x xxxx → 0010 0000 → 32 → 192.168.0.32/27
- 010x xxxx → 0100 0000 → 64 → 192.168.0.64/27
- …
- 111x xxxx → 1110 0000 → 224 → 192.168.0.224/27

Those are the (sub)network addresses.

Comment: Where did the "small enough to fit 7 subnets within your current /24 prefix" come from? I, too, would like to learn more about subnetting and this line has thrown me! Thank you :)

Comment: @BigChris: Well the OP's question also says "Which are the first seven subnets?", so the requirement comes from there. (Otherwise, there is no limit; you can subnet a /24 into two /25's if you wish.)

Comment: HaHa *DOH* *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

While the previous answers are all spot-on, I thought it'd be worthwhile to point out an implicit assumption we're making here. Both grawity's and BowlesCR's answers are assuming a fixed-length subnet mask, which need not be true. For example, the following subnet arrangement would also fulfill your requirements:

```
192.168.0.0/28   <-- NOT /27
192.168.0.16/27
192.168.0.48/27
192.168.0.80/27
192.168.0.112/27
192.168.0.144/27
192.168.0.176/27
```

Here's another:

```
192.168.0.0/28
192.168.0.16/28
192.168.0.32/28
192.168.0.48/26   <-- Oops, /26?!
192.168.0.112/27  <-- How about 27 instead...
192.168.0.144/28
192.168.0.160/28
```

These tend to be a lot more messy and tricky to calculate, so we understandably prefer to use the same subnet mask everywhere. To make it even easier on ourselves, we might just stick with octet boundaries and call it a day. For example, splitting up 10.0.0.0/8 into 7 subnets:

```
10.0.1.0/24
10.0.2.0/24
10.0.3.0/24
10.0.4.0/24
10.0.5.0/24
10.0.6.0/24
10.0.7.0/24
```

And lastly, another factor to consider is whether or not we're looking for the SMALLEST or LARGEST subnet mask that contains the number of hosts specified. grawity's answer alludes to this (/27 vs /28).